# border-bottom in tailwind css takes length of the parent element

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

i have a div with a few elements in it, and i want to achieve something like this

[image: example]

however when i add border-bottom to my h5, the border takes the length of the div not the h5 element like so

[image: second example]

this is the code or tailwind classes that i have used

```
     <section>
        <div className='grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-10'>
          <div>
            <h5 className='text-custom-orange font-medium border-solid border-b-2 border-custom-orange'>BLOG'S</h5>
            <h1 className='text-5xl font-medium'>Insights</h1>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `max-w-fit` utility to your `h5`.

This way, the [maximum width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width) of your `h5` element will fit its content.

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-10">
    <div>
      <h5 class="text-custom-orange font-medium border-solid border-b-2 border-custom-orange max-w-fit">BLOG'S</h5>
      <h1 class="text-5xl font-medium">Insights</h1>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JzrNZIz0OP)

---

Another solution is to apply text `decoration` utilities:

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid gap-10 md:grid-cols-2">
    <div>
      <h5 class="text-custom-orange font-medium underline decoration-gray-300 decoration-2 underline-offset-4">BLOG'S</h5>
      <h1 class="text-5xl font-medium">Insights</h1>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/HY8TO14OpF)

1. `underline` - Add an underline under the text  [[Docs]](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-decoration).
2. `decoration-gray-300` - Change the underline color to gray  [[Docs]](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-decoration-color).
3. `decoration-2` - Change the thickness of the underline to `2px`  [[Docs]](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-decoration-thickness).
4. `underline-offset-4` - controls the offset of the text underline  [[Docs]](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-underline-offset).

Comment: thanks for the answers both worked fine, especially the first explanation